# Regex formula for a file name

Tags: jquery, regex, input, field

I would like to allow a field in a form I have to allow only file names to be accepted. File names looks like this:

```
431714620407606949.jpg
```

18 digits [dot] jpg/gif/ico/png/tiff

Also I would like the field to accept multiple file name entries, so I want it to be like this:

```
431714620407606949.jpg,431714620407674859.jpg,837593620407606949.jpg
```

Comment: You should try something.

Comment: The real MacGyver would have found it, I'm sure.

Comment: we dont give you answers, we help you with what you have already tried.

Comment: The real MacGyver would done this in assembly.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new to regex and I'm not the real MacGyver lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it: http://regexr.com?353i8 (`/([\d]{18}\.)(jpg|png|gif)/g`)

This site will help you with your regex'

Comment: I've been searching a substitute for regexpal.com a long time ago. +1 For the site!

Comment: Sure, this is a great tool!

Comment: _"Also I would like the field to accept multiple file name entries"_ And you need to escape the `.` or it'll match any character.

Comment: was always looking for a site like this.

Comment: It accepts multiple entries, see the `/g` at the end. You're right about the `.`, have changed that, thanks!

Comment: _"to allow only file names to be accepted"_ - Your regex will also match strings that contain other characters. E.g., `"blah blah blah 123456789012345678.jpg xyz whatever"`.

Comment: It will match "file names" inside strings, yes. Like in a string with comma's and get the file names out of it.

Answer (score 3):

The following will match exactly one of those filenames:

```
/^\d{18}\.(jpg|gif|ico|png|tiff)$/
```

That is:

```
^                         beginning of string
\d{18}                    18 digits
\.                        a literal .
(jpg|gif|ico|png|tiff)    one of those extensions
$                         end of string
```

To match more with commas in between:

```
/^\d{18}\.(jpg|gif|ico|png|tiff)(,\d{18}\.(jpg|gif|ico|png|tiff))*$/
```

That is, the same pattern I already explained in detail, followed by zero or more occurrences of a comma plus the same pattern.

If you want to match upper- or lowercase file extensions add the `i` flag to the end:

```
/^\d{18}\.(jpg|gif|ico|png|tiff)(,\d{18}\.(jpg|gif|ico|png|tiff))*$/i
```