# quick ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

I am learning PHP functions and have this problem:

I need to change the function *ereg_replace*

```
$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j]);
```

to *preg_replace*

how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not a regular expression that you are using. What you want here is `str_replace`.

```
$row[$j] = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j]);
```

Rather read up about what regular expressions are and how they work.

Comment: you know I am learning from php.net and I am still on "E" (ereg_replace). Going alphabetically :)

Comment: Sure, but you'll need a real regex example to use regex'. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904590/regex-formula-for-a-file-name/16904648

Comment: regular expressions are my "Achilles heel"